# Как сейчас обстоят дела с WebSocket?

Tags: websocket

Здравствуйте. Как сейчас обстоят дела с WebSocket? На [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) всё ещё указано, что

> В конце ноября 2010 Adam Barth
> опубликовал результаты исследования
> надежности используемого протокола. По
> его результатам выяснилось, что в
> случае использования прозрачных
> прокси-серверов, возможна подмена кеша
> передаваемых данных с тем, что
> пользователи вместо реальных данных
> будут получать версию данных от
> злоумышленника. Проблема оказалась
> достаточно серьёзной для того, чтобы
> разработчики Firefox и Opera объявили
> о том, что в будущих версиях их
> браузеров поддержка веб-сокетов будет
> по умолчанию отключена вплоть до
> устранения проблемы небезопасности
> данного протокола (хотя осталась
> возможность их включить).

В то же время [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets) говорит, что да, могу. Насколько они безопасны в данный момент?

Comment: Вчитайтесь внимательнее в отрывок, который вы привели - ответ на ваш вопрос почти в самом его конце.

Comment: @0xFFh, но сможет ли рядовой пользователь их включить? Да и потом вдруг мой сайт кто-то будет ломать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из англоязычной [статьи](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) в wiki:

> A secure version of the WebSocket protocol is implemented in Firefox 6,[2] Safari 6, Google Chrome 14,[3] Opera 12.10 and Internet Explorer 10.[4]

Вроде бы, всё ок.

Вот ещё замечания по поводу безопасности websockets [на Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security).

Comment: Вроде бы... Ну, в целом я так понял, проблем с ними нет, можно сайтик будет написать.
Просто странно, что все связанные с websocket обсуждения, которые выплывают в поисковиках на первых местах, датируются <2012, как будто технологией вообще никто не пользуется. Хотя по запросу java real time web applications находятся именно статьи с использованием websockets

Comment: Если вдруг не видели, посмотрите надстройку над Websockets: [wamp](http://wamp.ws/) (web application messaging protocol) и его реализацию под Java/Android [Autobahn](http://autobahn.ws/android/)